# The Email thumbnail could not be retrieved in Individual Email Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, marketingcloudapi

We sent an email using the Journey Builder, when we checked the Individual Email Results we were able to check all the tracking details but for the email image it showed "**The email thumbnail could not be retrieved**". When we checked the same record via System Admin user we were able to see all the images. Also the same person was able to see email images of few records that were sent earlier. Is there any permission that we missed or is it something related to some settings.

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue in SFMC, pls refer:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001Spi0QAC

Reference:
[SFMC Known Issues](https://sprignaturemoves.com/sfmcki.php)